# How to use responseJson data from database in picker in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i fetch a  response Jeson   and i need  to use it  in picker  but when run the code  i have this problem  :  TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.dataSource.map')

whem i use  a flat list it run  whitout problem

```
    <Picker selectedValue = {this.state.time} onValueChange = {this.updatetime}>
    {this.state.dataSource.map((item, key)=>(
        <Picker.Item label={item} value={item} key={key} />)
        )}

        </Picker>
```

dateFunction = () =>{

```
fetch('http://192.168.1.111:8000//mobreservedTimes?date='+this.state.date , {
  method: 'get',


 /* body: JSON.stringify({

    datepik: 20-7-2019  ,

  })*/

}).then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {


this.setState({
  isLoading: false,
  dataSource: responseJson.avTimes,
}, function(){

});


      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        alert(error);
      });
```

TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.dataSource.map')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your code to

```js
{this.state.dataSource && (<Picker selectedValue = {this.state.time} onValueChange = {this.updatetime}>
    {this.state.dataSource.map((item, key)=>(
        <Picker.Item label={item} value={item} key={key} />)
        )}

</Picker>)}
```

The idea is that, check to make sure `this.state.dataSource` is not null before render the `Picker`

Comment: Thanks, it runs and fetches data